# Show $(\forall x\in I)\quad f(x)=1 \quad \mbox{or} \quad (\forall x\in I)\quad f(x)=-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ a continuous function defined from I to $\mathbb{R}$ such that:
>   $$(\forall x\in I)\quad (f(x))^{2}=1$$
>
> Show that  :
>   $(\forall x\in I)\quad f(x)=1 \quad \mbox{or} \quad  (\forall x\in I)\quad f(x)=-1$

Comment: Hint: Proof by contradiction and use Intermediate value theorem to find a root of $f$ in $I$, contradicting the condition $f^2(x) = 1$.

Comment: So your $f^2(x)$ is the iterated application $f(f(x))$, not $f(x)$ squared? – In that case the statement would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think that $f^2(x)$ means $(f(x))^2$ and not $f(f(x))$.

Suppose to the contrary,  that there are $u,v \in I$ such that $f(u)=-1$ and $f(v)=1$. The intermediate value theorem gives now a point $w \in I$ with $f(w)=0$, hence

$$0 =f^2(w)=1,$$

which is absurd !